# Sending and Receiving data with MySQL + Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I have a MySQL Database on my server. I need my android app to two things.

1. Android App needs to send 3 different integers. The MySQL database already has these data types set in them. I'm guessing I need to write a PHP script and basically have Android execute it, correct?
2. Then the Database needs to send a float and an integer back to the Android app. Once again, I'm guessing this needs a PHP script executed by Android as well.

I am not familiar with using PHP and remote databases within Android, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to expose a service that listens and waits for those parameters to arrive. I'd make a PHP page that takes those params from the URL and processes them, anyway I'm not familiar with PHP either but shouldn't be so hard. You should then have to pass those parameters constructing the URL dynamically from the Android device. Could be a starting point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really simple if you're just doing an INSERT.

In the Android application set it up like this:

```
try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/insert.php?i="+cUser.getUserId());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
```

where cUser.getUserId() is the integer you want to pass to insert.php as the $_GET['i'] variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tunneling through PHP/Web Server you can also call the mySQL DB directly - if the DB is installed on a server with an external IP (I am guessing it is) and mySQL configured to take TCP/IP connections from the outside world. You can use [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) directly, or some framework for connection to the DB.

Use the following JDBC string (see also [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)):

```
jdbc:mysql://<yourhost>:<yourport>/<yourdatabase>
```

Standard port is 3306.

You may need to enable networking in mySQL; see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

In this case, you do not need PHP or a web server at all. Having said all that, a middle tier (i.e. PHP/Web Server) might, on the long run, be what you are after if you are attempting to write an application with some logic on the server.